# Matching in Perl

Tags: perl, matching

I am trying to get text in between two dots of a line, but my program returns the entire line.

For example: I have text which looks like:

> My sampledata 1,2 for perl .version 1_1.

I used the following match statement

```
$x =~ m/(\.)(.*)(\.)/;
```

My output for $x should be version 1_1, but I am getting the entire line as my match.

Comment: $x ist not your match, it's the input for your regular expression.

Answer (score 5):

In your code, the value of $x will not change after the match.

When $x is successfully matched with [m/(.)(.*)(.)/](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#m%2F_PATTERN_%2Fmsixpodualngc), your three capture groups will contain '.', 'version 1_1' and '.' respectively (in the order given). $2 will give you 'version 1_1'.

Considering that you might probably only want the part 'version 1_1', you need not capture the two dots. This code will give you the same result:

```
$x =~ m/\.(.*)\./;
print $1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
my $str = "My sampledata 1,2 for perl .version 1_1.";
$str =~ /\.\K[^.]+(?=\.)/;
print $&;
```

The period must be escaped out of a character class.

`\K` resets all that has been matched before (you can replace it by a lookbehind `(?<=\.)`)

`[^.]` means any character except a period.

For several results, you can do this:

```
my $str = "qwerty .target 1.target 2.target 3.";
my @matches = ($str =~ /\.\K[^.]+(?=\.)/g);
print join("\n", @matches);
```

If you don't want to use twice a period you can do this:

```
my $str = "qwerty .target 1.target 2.target 3.";
my @matches = ($str =~ /\.([^.]+)\./g);
print join("\n", @matches)."\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be simple enough to do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my @tests = (
    "test one. get some stuff. extra",
    "stuff with only one dot.",
    "another test line.capture this. whatever",
    "last test . some data you want.",
    "stuff with only no dots",
);

for my $test (@tests) {
   # For this example, I skip $test if the match fails,
   # otherwise, I move on do stuff with $want
   next if $test !~ /\.(.*)\./;
   my $want = $1;
   print "got: $want\n";
}
```

#### Output

```
$ ./test.pl
got:  get some stuff
got: capture this
got:  some data you want
```